# USB behavior changes when laptop is plugged

Tags: linux-kernel, usb

I have a USB camera (from IDS) and I wanted to plug it to my new laptop. I installed the software and everything was fine until all frames dropped. After an long investigation I finally understood that, the frames dropped uniquely when the laptop was plugged. When the laptop is only on battery, everything is fine.
I guess there is then a different behavior of the USB port between plugged and battery. 
Is there any way to see what are the differences and to correct this issue ?

Thanks